# PowerShell Variables `${$}`, `${^}` and `$?`

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Does anyone know what the following variables are used for in PowerShell:

- `${$}`
- `${^}`
- `$?`

From what I can tell `${^}` and `${$}` both relate to the last executed command line (if you're running these as a script via ISE they relate to the command executed before the script was run, rather than the prior line in the same script).  The difference seems to be that ${^} returns the command up to the first whitespace character, whilst ${$} returns everything after the last whitespace character.  i.e.

- `$chevron = $lastCommand -replace '^([^\s]*).*$', '$1'`
- `$dollar = $lastCommand -replace '^.*?([^\s]*)$', '$1'`

`$?` meanwhile seems to always return `true`.

I spotted these variables when they showed up in the ISE's auto-complete feature.

I'm sure this is documented, but I've struggled to find the right search terms to find the answers / anything but noise.

Comment: I similarly found this difficult to google, but was also not the first to ask about $? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32120202/2796058

Comment: About Automatic Variables: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx is the official documentation of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $?:

$?  Contains the execution status of the last operation. Equivalent to %errorlevel% in the CMD shell. See also $LastExitCode below.
It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed. ReadOnly, AllScope. (https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html)

The rest is documented there too.

Answer (score 3):

Googling by character name instead of the character itself worked!

http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens

`${^}` can also be written `$^`.  This gives the first token of the last command.  This is similar to what I'd said in the question, only a token may include whitespace; rather things are split based on the parsed code.  To illustrate: `'number 1', 'number 2' | Write-Host` would return `number 1` instead of `'number`.

`${$}` / `$$` likewise returns the last token.  i.e. after running `write-host -ForegroundColor green -Object 'hello, is it me you''re looking for?'`, `$$` gives `hello, is it me you're looking for?`.

`$?` returns true if the previous command was successful.  To demonstrate where it's false, running `1/0` then `$?` will give a false result.

Answer (score 1):

> $$
>
> Contains the last token in the last line received by the current
>   session.
>
> $?
>
> Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE
>   if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.
>
> $^
>
> Contains the first token in the last line received by the session.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables